# Barcode scanner Library project

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have integrated barcode scanner library project with phonegap. On loading the .apk file, the app gets opened.  I can see the HTML file with scan button. As soon as I click on scan button, the camera gets opened in landscape mode.  Within 5 seconds, the app crashes and gives an error message: "Unfortunately App has stopped".  Please help me with this issue.

Here is the logcat file:

```
09-30 05:34:58.069: I/CordovaLog(852): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
09-30 05:34:58.119: D/CordovaActivity(852): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
09-30 05:34:58.989: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 104K, 9% free 2477K/2712K, paused 216ms, total 219ms
09-30 05:34:59.000: I/dalvikvm-heap(852): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.149MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-30 05:34:59.069: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 8% free 3097K/3336K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
09-30 05:34:59.119: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 3097K/3336K, paused 11ms+6ms, total 50ms
09-30 05:34:59.119: D/dalvikvm(852): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 24ms
09-30 05:34:59.119: I/dalvikvm-heap(852): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.625MB for 500416-byte allocation
09-30 05:34:59.189: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 7% free 3585K/3828K, paused 61ms, total 61ms
09-30 05:34:59.419: D/CordovaWebView(852): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: unknown
09-30 05:34:59.439: D/JsMessageQueue(852): Set native->JS mode to 2
09-30 05:34:59.439: D/CordovaActivity(852): CordovaActivity.init()
09-30 05:34:59.449: D/CordovaWebView(852): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
09-30 05:34:59.449: D/PluginManager(852): init()
09-30 05:34:59.472: D/PluginManager(852): <plugin> tags are deprecated, please use <features> instead. <plugin> will no longer work as of Cordova 3.0
09-30 05:34:59.479: D/CordovaWebView(852): >>> loadUrlNow()
09-30 05:34:59.491: D/Config(852): Unlimited access to network resources
09-30 05:34:59.491: I/CordovaLog(852): Found start page location: index.html
09-30 05:34:59.491: I/CordovaLog(852): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
09-30 05:34:59.491: D/CordovaActivity(852): Resuming the App
09-30 05:34:59.491: D/CordovaActivity(852): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
09-30 05:34:59.549: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(852): Ignore this event
09-30 05:34:59.739: D/gralloc_goldfish(852): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-30 05:35:00.089: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(852): Ignore this event
09-30 05:35:01.279: D/CordovaActivity(852): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
09-30 05:35:01.879: D/CordovaLog(852): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 4 : Viewport argument value "320;" for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
09-30 05:35:01.879: V/Web Console(852): Viewport argument value "320;" for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix. at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:4
09-30 05:35:02.049: D/chromium(852): Unknown chromium error: -6
09-30 05:35:03.650: D/chromium(852): Unknown chromium error: -6
09-30 05:35:03.689: D/chromium(852): Unknown chromium error: -6
09-30 05:35:03.689: D/Cordova(852): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
09-30 05:35:03.689: D/CordovaActivity(852): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
09-30 05:35:04.269: D/CordovaNetworkManager(852): Connection Type: 3g
09-30 05:35:04.269: D/CordovaActivity(852): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
09-30 05:35:04.279: D/CordovaNetworkManager(852): Connection Type: 3g
09-30 05:35:04.299: D/CordovaActivity(852): onMessage(spinner,stop)
09-30 05:35:04.449: D/TilesManager(852): Starting TG #0, 0x2a1ba0d0
09-30 05:35:05.779: D/CordovaActivity(852): onMessage(spinner,stop)
09-30 05:35:09.729: D/CordovaActivity(852): Paused the application!
09-30 05:35:09.729: D/CordovaWebView(852): Handle the pause
09-30 05:35:10.708: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 810K, 23% free 3205K/4148K, paused 9ms+19ms, total 111ms
09-30 05:35:10.708: D/dalvikvm(852): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 98ms
09-30 05:35:10.708: I/dalvikvm-heap(852): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.860MB for 635812-byte allocation
09-30 05:35:10.891: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 60K, 10% free 3766K/4148K, paused 118ms, total 145ms
09-30 05:35:10.998: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 3766K/4148K, paused 106ms, total 106ms
09-30 05:35:11.028: I/dalvikvm-heap(852): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.278MB for 500416-byte allocation
09-30 05:35:11.119: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 9% free 4254K/4640K, paused 89ms, total 89ms
09-30 05:35:11.238: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 9% free 4265K/4640K, paused 7ms+5ms, total 119ms
09-30 05:35:11.481: I/PlatformSupportManager(852): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:80)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.showHelpOnFirstLaunch(CaptureActivity.java:682)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onCreate(CaptureActivity.java:154)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-30 05:35:12.079: W/CaptureActivity(852):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-30 05:35:12.149: I/Choreographer(852): Skipped 174 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-30 05:35:12.489: I/PlatformSupportManager(852): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface for SDK 9
09-30 05:35:12.499: I/GingerbreadOpenCamera(852): Opening camera #0
09-30 05:35:12.919: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Screen resolution: Point(1280, 736)
09-30 05:35:12.929: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Supported preview sizes: 640x480 352x288 320x240 
09-30 05:35:12.929: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Found best approximate preview size: Point(640, 480)
09-30 05:35:12.929: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Camera resolution: Point(640, 480)
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Initial camera parameters: picture-size-values=640x480,352x288,320x240;prop-facing=back;preview-fps-range=5,30;min-exposure-compensation=-6;vertical-view-angle=42.5;horizontal-view-angle=54.8;whitebalance=auto;jpeg-thumbnail-height=384;jpeg-quality=90;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p,rgba8888;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=90;focus-mode=fixed;preview-format=yuv420sp;preview-size=640x480;focal-length=4.31;video-frame-format=yuv420p;picture-format-values=jpeg;max-exposure-compensation=6;exposure-compensation=0;preview-frame-rate-values=30,24,20,15,10,5;exposure-compensation-step=0.5;prop-orientation=90;preview-frame-rate=24;focus-mode-values=fixed;picture-size=640x480;jpeg-thumbnail-width=512;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,daylight,twilight;picture-format=jpeg;preview-fps-range-values=(5,30);jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=320x240,0x0;preview-size-values=640x480,352x288,320x240
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Supported values: null
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Settable value: null
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Supported values: [fixed]
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Settable value: null
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Supported values: [fixed]
09-30 05:35:12.989: I/CameraConfiguration(852): Settable value: null
09-30 05:35:13.059: I/PlatformSupportManager(852): Using implementation class com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.HoneycombAsyncTaskExecInterface of interface com.google.zxing.client.android.common.executor.AsyncTaskExecInterface for SDK 11
09-30 05:35:13.079: I/dalvikvm(852): threadid=20: stack overflow on call to Lcom/google/zxing/MultiFormatReader;.extracted1:LL
09-30 05:35:13.079: I/dalvikvm(852):   method requires 12+20+8=40 bytes, fp is 0x49b0c308 (8 left)
09-30 05:35:13.079: I/dalvikvm(852):   expanding stack end (0x49b0c300 to 0x49b0c000)
09-30 05:35:13.079: I/dalvikvm(852): Shrank stack (to 0x49b0c300, curFrame is 0x49b0ffdc)
09-30 05:35:13.079: W/dalvikvm(852): threadid=20: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-30 05:35:13.099: I/AutoFocusManager(852): Current focus mode 'fixed'; use auto focus? false
09-30 05:35:13.859: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 926K, 22% free 3950K/5008K, paused 8ms+129ms, total 522ms
09-30 05:35:16.069: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 392K, 19% free 4078K/5008K, paused 82ms+208ms, total 1381ms
09-30 05:35:16.069: D/dalvikvm(852): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1237ms
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-98
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader.extracted1(MultiFormatReader.java:159)
09-30 05:35:16.069: E/AndroidRuntime(852):  at com.google.zxing.Mult
09-30 05:35:16.811: D/dalvikvm(852): GC_CONCURRENT freed 644K, 21% free 4003K/5008K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 301ms
09-30 05:35:16.811: D/dalvikvm(852): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 207ms
09-30 05:35:18.500: D/dalvikvm(852): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1830ms
```